# Obtaining row indices of a matrix that satisfies a condition in Python

Tags: python, matrix-indexing

I have been trying to obtain all the row indices of the matrix (A) that contains the element nd.

The size of A is 4M*4, it takes ~ 12 sec  for this operation.

Link to the file : [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1elSabMbRnwZDNCMmM4UDlWMHc/view?usp=sharing)

```
# Download the file named elementconnectivity before running this small script 


A=np.loadtxt('elementconnectivity') 
A=A.astype(int)
nd=1103
v=[i for i in range(len(A)) if nd in A[i]]
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Please share sample values of `A` and `nd` if you can. This will give us more idea as to what kind of operation are you doing and which solution would fit better.

Comment: Hello Vivek - I have given the sample values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `numpy` anyway, this speeds up a lot with some more numpy functions. Your current method on my system:

```
%timeit v=[i for i in range(len(A)) if nd in A[i]]
1 loop, best of 3: 4.23 s per loop
```

Instead, this is about 40x faster:

```
%timeit v = np.where(np.sum((A == nd), axis=1) > 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.2 ms per loop
```

You can also look at `np.in1d` which is similar to the `A == nd` I have used above, but can compare with lists (something like A == nd1 or nd2 or nd3).

Comment: I found this even takes much lesser time

v=np.where(A==nd)[0]

Comment: That will not give you what you are looking for! This is giving you all elements where A == nd. But you wanted to know what rows have any element == nd. That is why you have to sum it over one axis.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks a better way to accomplish this is to use iterators instead of lists

```
idxs = (i for i in xrange(len(A)) if nd in A[i])
idxs.next()
```

Comment: got an error : <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000007FFFEFFC3A8>

Comment: that is not an error, is the reference to a generator. [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) do not give a result right away, instead, every time you need a value you use the method **next** to get it.

Comment: Could you please explain how do I get back the values in the array, I apologize I am not aware of this

Comment: I update the answer to give a simple example how to use the generator

Comment: While I use the list that I mentioned i get v as an array, but if I use the generator that you mentioned here, I am only getting 1 element not the entire array. Any work around ?

Comment: You can iterate over generators like you do with lists: `for idx in idxs:`.

Comment: While the 'idxs = (i for i in xrange(len(A))' if nd in A[i]) takes very less time, the 'for idx in idxs: a.append(idx)' takes a lot of time. Overall both list as well as generators take almost equal times.